# hibernate join using an

Tags: java, hibernate, join, annotations, hql

I am trying to do a hibernate join - the query seemingly works but when i try to cast from the object returned into the type i want it to be it doesnt work...im assuming because it has the joined table info too..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PSNG_SMRY")
public class PSNG_SMRY implements Serializable, Comparable<PSNG_SMRY>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment"  , strategy = "increment")
    @Printable
    public Integer SMRY_ID;
    public Integer DEV_ID;
    public Integer RPTD_TRN_ID;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy="smry", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        public TRN trn;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TRN")
public class TRN implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Integer TRN_ID;
        public String TRN_SCTN
        public String TRN_SYMB;

         @OneToOne
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        private PSNG_SMRY smry;
}
```

I found this one to one mapping example here - [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/)

And when I get the Object back from hibernate I try to cast it to PSNG_SMRY and it wont work - how am i am to do a join where i get the PSNG_SMRY info and the TRN_SYMB from the TRN table back using a join?

**EDIT:**

I get an invalid cast exception - `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to PSNG_SMRY`

query code:

```
//code  from some function that sets up all queries
String qQuery = "FROM PSNG_SMRY P, TRN T WHERE  T.TRN_ID = P.RPTD_TRN_ID and P.FIR_AXLE_PASD_DT > sysdate - :timeLimit and P.FIR_AXLE_PASD_DT < sysdate - 1/24 ORDER BY P.FIR_AXLE_PASD_DT";

hqlParamList.add(new HQLParams("timeLimit", timeLimit)); //some list to pass to hibernate and then parameterize the queury

result = queryDatabase(qQuery, q4Query, hqlParamList);



public QueryResult queryDatabase(String qQuery, String q4Query,
        List<HQLParams> params) {
    QueryResult results = new QueryResult();

    jwdsqa = new Connection("JWDSQA");
    jwds4qa = new Connection("JWDS4QA");

    results.qa = jwdsqa.retrieve(qQuery, params);
    results.qa4 = jwds4qa.retrieve(q4Query, params);

    return results;
}
```

**EDIT:
This is the connection class - it is just used to get the session information and do all the hibernate stuff such as getting data...**

```
public class Connection {

public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Connection.class);

   Session session;
   String sessionName;

public Connection(String name){
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(name).openSession();

sessionName = name;
    if(session.isConnected()){
        //System.out.println(name + " - Connected");
    }
}

public Session getSession(){
    return session;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Object> retrieve(String qry, List<HQLParams> paramList)
{
    Transaction transaction = null;
    List<Object> obj = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String queryString = qry;

        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);

        if(paramList != null)
        {
            for(HQLParams param: paramList)
            {
                query.setParameter(param.paramName, param.params);
            }
        }


        List<Object> obj_ = query.list();
        obj = obj_;
        //session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(ex.getMessage() + "\n" + ex.getStackTrace());
        transaction.rollback();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        logger.error(ex.getMessage() + "\n" + ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
        //System.out.println("Closing session " + sessionName);
    }

    return obj;
}
}
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` - do you get an exception? Other behavior? Which exception? + show you're querying code.

Comment: There is no RPTD_TRN_ID field in the entity PSNG_SMRY, so it's hard to explain how your query should be written instead. What's sure is that not only you don't respect Java naming conventions, but none of the fields means anything, which makes the code and the query very very hard to understand. Use real words.

Comment: I'm not familiar with such a `Connection` object in Hibernate API. Are you using direct JDBC? Or some 3rd party except for Hibernate that provides this API?

Comment: @JBNizet the reason why the fields are not named using Java naming conventions is because instead of using annotations for each field you can name the field the exact name of the column and hibernate will make the link without the use of annotations...and I updated the question as I took snippets from the code as there are a lot of fields...

Comment: @yair I updated the question to include the Connection class...no im not using JDBC - using hibernate 4.1.2

Comment: @JonH: and this is an extremely bad idea. It makes the code unreadable, and foces you to change lots of code if you decide to change the name of a column. Annotations are there precisely to be able to mak the code readable and respect Java naming conventions, whatever the naming convention for tables and columns are.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out - the reason why I was getting the casting error was hibernate was returning both the `PSNG_SMRY` and `TRN` objects back as an `Object[]` - and not as one Object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want PSNG_SMRY instances you should not have to ask for the TRN table. This is provided for you when you use using JPA mapping

```
   FROM PSNG_SMRY P 
        WHERE P.FIR_AXLE_PASD_DT > sysdate - :timeLimit 
        and P.FIR_AXLE_PASD_DT < sysdate - 1/24 
        ORDER BY P.FIR_AXLE_PASD_DT
```

If you do not get the TRN for the retrieved PSNG_SMRY objects then it means there is a mapping error because you are telling Hibernate how to retrieve the TRN for a PSNG_SMRY in your annotation

```
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="smry", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public TRN trn;
```